# TypeError: mongodb.ObjectId is not a constructor

Tags: mongodb, express, axios, mern

[Code : app.post('/update-item',function(req,res){
db.collection('items').findOneAndUpdate({_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id)}, {$set: {text: req.body.text}}, function (req,res) {
res.send("Success")
})][1]

Answer (score 0):

your code looks a little bit off for me, I would approach it like this:

```js
const MyModel = require('<PATH_FOR_YOUR_MODEL>');
app.post("/update-item", async (req,res)){
 const id = req.body.id
 const text = req.body.text
 await MyModel findByIdAndUpdate(id, text);
 res.status(200).send('Success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem following brad schiff's [Learn JavaScript: Full-Stack from Scratch](https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-javascript-full-stack-from-scratch/)  course.
the problem seems to be this line of code on top of the file:

```
let mongodb = require('mongodb');
```

it's not enough it seems, I fixed it by adding the line below :

```
let mongoObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
```

and used mongoObjectId  instead of mongodb.ObjectId (in your code change these two with eachother)

---

I also changed the first line to:

```
let mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

because it caused some other errors before;

Answer (score -1):

first declare the `ObjectId` on top!!

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId
```

and then, use the variable `ObjectId` instead of `mongodb.ObjectId` !!

like,

```
db.collection('items').findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectId(req.body.id) }, { $set: { text: req.body.text } }, function () {
    res.send("Success")
})
```